# Can i connect my 144hz monitor for Acer nitro 5 laptop with a external display that has a higher refresh rate?

Tags: windows-10, display

I want to use my Benq monitor that is 144Hz and my laptop is only 60Hz but just want to know if that will work with my type of laptop? model number (AN515-53-55G9)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work fine.  Your monitor supports speed *up to* 144 hertz.  It will function at a lower refresh rate without issues.

Comment: I connected my laptop to my monitor using HDMI, but for some reason when i go on the Nvidia control panel, and i go to the refresh rate, the max its showing for refresh rate is 60 nothing more. Am i doing something wrong? or is it not compatible?

Comment: @IvanMartinez Make sure you have the latest nvidia driver.  but if thats what it is saying, then that is the max hertz your gpu is putting out.